# In this programe why we add the semicolon out of for loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,l,t;
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(l=1,t=n/10;t!=0;t/=10,l*=10);
    printf("\nThe pattern\n");
    for(t=n;t!=0;t%=l,l/=10)
        printf("\n%d",t);
}
```

Comment: Because all the code the loop should do is already included in the header, there's nothing meaningful left in the body to do; the semicolon is a shorter alternative for having a pair of empty braces... Admitted, this kind of loop is not really beginner-friendly ;)

Comment: It is a good idea to use braces (for loops), so you do not get caught with your trousers down. i.e. `{ /* empty */ }` and `{ printf(....); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this programe why we add the semicolon out of for loop?

Because all the code the loop should do is already included in the header, there's nothing meaningful left in the body to do.

The semicolon is a shorter alternative for having a pair of empty braces like

```
for(l = 1, t = n / 10; t != 0; t /= 10, l *= 10) { }
```

Actually, the semicolon is an expression on its own, though an empty one, it would be equivalent to explicitly telling not to do anything at all like

```
for( ... )
    (void)0; // does nothing
```

Admitted, this loop is not really beginner-friendly and requires a bit of experience in reading ;)

An easier to read variant effectively doing the same could look like:

```
l = 1;
for(t = n / 10; t != 0; t /= 10)
{
    l *= 10;
}
```

Now the loop covers five lines, though, and compactness obviously was the reason of the original code's author to write it as it is.

Having compact code is fine, though readability should never suffer from. This piece of code is a pretty good example for overly (thus bad) compact code. A counter-example might be using the ternary operator in favour of an if-else clause – provided you don't get endlessly long code lines in trying to apply so...